# GeoFire Query Showing All Markers

Tags: java, android, markers, geofire

So I have multiple locations in my FireBase Database:

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTrgU.png)

And wrote this to loop through all of these nodes, extract the longitudes and latitudes, and then display them as markers.

```
    final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("locations");
    final GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);

    //Add a location
    //geoFire.setLocation("meetFar2", new GeoLocation(26.173027, -80.252871));

    final GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(userLocation.latitude, userLocation.longitude), 5.7);
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Key %s entered the search area at [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
        Query locationQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("locations");
        locationQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
              Double latitude = (Double) snap.child("l/0").getValue();
              Double longitude = (Double) snap.child("l/1").getValue();
              LatLng meetLatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
              googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(meetLatLng));
            }
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
        });
      }

      @Override
      public void onKeyExited(String key) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Key %s is no longer in the search area", key));
      }

      @Override
      public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Key %s moved within the search area to [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
      }

      @Override
      public void onGeoQueryReady() {
      }

      @Override
      public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There was an error with this query " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
```

This is all done within onMapReady after I got the user's last known location (set as userLocation). However, when I run the program, the map displays all markers if at least 1 key is in the query's radius. How can I only display the results from the query within the radius as markers?

Comment: [Please Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833857/multiple-marker-icon-move-by-updating-geofire-location-in-google-maps-for-androi) answerd by Mustofa Kamal

Answer (score 0):

Realized that the initial queryAtLocation query was returning the correct amount of points from my database, so I removed the second query within it. Code now looks like this:

```
final GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(userLocation.latitude, userLocation.longitude), 7.0);
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Key %s entered the search area at [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));

        LatLng meetLatLng = new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(meetLatLng));
      }
```